# NAT traversal, IPSEC and TCP/UDP header checksum

Tags: ipsec

When IPSEC is configured with NAT traversal, does the receiver calculate the checksums twice (i.e. first for the outer UDP header and then for the ESP encapsulated packet (TCP or UDP)? If yes, where does it get the "original" source ip and port from?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The cleartext packet with its original source IP header is encrypted/encapsulated in an ESP packet. This encrypted packet is encapsulated in a UDP (port 4500 with NAT traversal enabled) datagram. The inside 'original' packet is not tampered with and therefore needs to be re-evaluated when it gets to its destination. The outer packet's data portion may as well be nonsense to the encryption device (that's the point of encryption) so it wouldn't be possible to evaluate it before it was decrypted.

So more accurately, assuming the 'receiver' is the destination of the original packet, only validates the checksum for the packet once. The endpoint device (router/firewall) performing the enc(ryption/apsulation) will check the outer-packet once.

Comment: thanks...what about the router/firewall where the IPSEC tunnel terminates. Does that calculate the checksum twice or only for outer packet?